# Counting renewals during count of subscription sold

Tags: php, mysql

I've a table in which write every subscription sold of my magazine, like this:

```
USERID | DATE | 

31 | 2011-09-22 | 
54 | 2011-09-22 | 
59 | 2011-09-23 | 
11 | 2011-10-02 | 
88 | 2011-10-05 |
31 | 2011-10-06 | 
17 | 2011-10-12 | 
54 | 2011-10-15 |
31 | 2011-11-05 |
54 | 2011-11-12 |
```

Now, for statistical purpose, i need to having an outcome in which i see, for every single month, how many subscriptions i've sold and how many users have already bought once this.

For instance, if we look the datas on top, i should have an outcome likie this:

```
DATE | SOLD | RENEWAL 
 09  | 3    | 0
 10  | 5    | 1
 11  | 2    | 2
```

I can to group the subscriptions sold monthly, but i can't add the "renewal" info.

```
  SELECT COUNT( * ) AS  sold, MONTH(date) FROM table_sold WHERE date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 13 MONTH GROUP BY YEAR( date ) , MONTH( date ) ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 1,15
```

In this way i only have an outcome like this:

```
 DATE | SOLD
  09  | 3    
  10  | 5
  11  | 2
```

I've tried several option, with subquery, union and so on, but without successful.
There is to consider that the table has 70.000 entries and a query with a hard scan could be a problem.

In your opinion is there a way in mysql or i've to take the idea to make it in php?

Comment: do you need to handle cases where someone let their sub lapse, and then resubscribed later on? Would that count as a renewal, or a new sub? If you don't need to handle renewals, then you could just count how many hits every ID (`n`) has, and then it's 1 sale + (n-1) renewals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea.  Look at the first date for each user.  Then count renewals in every month that is not the first date:

```
select year(date), month(date), count(*) as sold,
       sum(case when date <> firstdate then 1 else 0 end) as renewals
from subscriptions s join
     (select userid, min(date) as firstdate
      from subscriptions s
      group by userid
     ) su
     on s.userid = su.userid
group by year(date), month(date)
order by year(date), month(date);
```